# Show All user's in table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to display all registered users in table. How can I set loop to fetch all registered user and display in html from. Below code is my html user table format:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  <td><a href="#">Admin</a></td>
  <td>4th of May 2010 - 9:31</td>
  <td>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/icons/pencil.png" alt="Edit" /></a>
    <a href="#" class="confirmation"><img src="images/icons/cross.png" alt="Delete" /></a><!-- to create a tooltip-style confirmation, just add .confirmation to the <a>-tag -->
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what did you done so far?

Comment: i completed registration and login page, through this all user can registered and login success fully, now i'm trying to fetch all registered user's, i have no idea how i can use while loop to fetch all user's to show above mentioned html format.

Comment: where is your query?

Comment: can you please describe me how can i set query and fetch data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assumed your table as 'users'.

i simple display users name in table row, you can modify according to your needs,

```
 mysql_connect('your_server', 'username', 'password') or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("your_database_name") or die(mysql_error()); 

$query="select * from users";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$arr = array();
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    echo "<tr>".$row['name']."</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Ayyanar G :-) Thank you very very very much, i'm really excited when i done by following your code. It's amazing and working fine. again bundle of thanks

Comment: you are welcome... improve yourself everytime, have a great time